# Creating an object with var for object key?

Tags: javascript

I have an object:

```
"locales": {
    "en":["au", "uk"],
    "de":["ch", "de"]
 }
```

I check if a language is in this object then create the object with just the found language.

```
var language = 'en';

if(language in locales){

    locales = { language : locales[language]};
    ...
```

But logging locales gives:

```
{ language: [ 'au', 'uk' ] }
```

Where I would expect to see:

```
{ en: [ 'au', 'uk' ] }
```

The new object is using a string rather than var for the object key - how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) assignment here,

```
var language = 'en';
if(language in locales){
    locales = { [language] : locales[language]};
```

You can't use a variable directly as a key to an object.

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/5dd6hLwx/)

Answer (score 1):

> locales = { language : locales[language]};

You have 2 problems:

1. You set the key `locales`
2. you use the `locales` twice

Do it like this:

```
var locales = {
    "en": ["au", "uk"],
    "de": ["ch", "de"]
        },
language = 'en';

if (locales[language]){
    locales = locales[language];
}
```

### console.log(locales)

Output:
[image]

Comment: i need the object to be called locales.

Comment: Updated the answer for you

Answer (score 1):

```
var locals = {}
locals[language] = locales[language];
```